# Не могу зарегистрироватся в openweathermap.org

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyowm

Мне нужен api ключ что-бы работать с pyowm, но когда я хочу зарегистрироватся.
У меня просто не загружает эту страницу.

Интернет работает, пишет что надо проверить подключение к интернету(страница не с игрой дино)

Что мне делать? 
Кто знает может альтернативные способы узнать погоду,ветер и тому подобное.

Comment: Доступ к сайту home.openweathermap.org блокируется на территории РФ. Решение — переехать в другую страну.

Comment: @andreymal а прокси юзать не варик?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin полумеры какие-то.

Comment: @andreymal т.е. проще уехать из рф?)

Answer (score 0):

Все было просто, помог понять -  andreymal.

Надо просто поставить vpn

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, это и есть ответ, других ответов у данного вопроса нет.

Comment: @insolor OK ...